# Excel highlight row if 2 cell values match

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

if I have cell D2 (input value 100) and M2 equals the value from another sheet and that value matches the value of D2 how do I highlight the whole row not just the cells?

Comment: best I can make happen is highlight one cell

Comment: It sounds like you're using conditional formatting. Can you post a screenshot showing the setup for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Conditional Formatting on each cell of the Row that you want to Highlight as follows
`Highlight Cells Rules`
`More Rules`
 in the Box where you have Select Rule Type choose `Use a formula to determine which cell to format`
in the Box Format values where this formula is True write:
`= d2=m2`
Then Format as you like, then ok, ok.
Repeat the same for each cell that you want to highlight on the same `Row 2`